# Confusion about calculating sample correlation in r

Tags: r, statistics

I have been tasked with manually calculating the sample correlation between two datasets (D$Nload and D$Pload), and then compare the result with R's in built cor() function.

I calculate the sample correlation with

```
cov(D$Nload,D$Pload, use="complete.obs")/(sd(D$Nload)*sd(D$Pload, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Which gives me the result 0.5693599

Then I try using R's cov() function

```
cor(D[, c("Nload","Pload")], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

which gives me the result:

```
          Nload     Pload
Nload 1.0000000 0.6244952
Pload 0.6244952 1.0000000
```

Which is a different result. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Could you post some example data where this happens?

Comment: Do you wan't to see the data in vectors D$Nload and D$Pload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because when you call `sd()` on a single vector, it cannot check if the data is pairwise complete. Example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rexp(100)
y[1] <- NA
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

So here we have

```
df[seq(2), ]
           x         y
1  1.0879645        NA
2 -0.3919369 0.2191193
```

We see that while the second row is pairwise complete (all columns used for your computation are not NA), the first row is not. However, if you calculate `sd()` on just a single column, it doesn't have any information about the pairs. So in your case, `sd(df$x)` will use all the available data, although it should avoid the first row.

```
cov(df$x, df$y, use = "complete.obs") / (sd(df$x)*sd(df$y, na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 0.09301583

cor(df$x, df$y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
[1] 0.09313766
```

But if you remove the first row from your computation, the result is equal

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
cov(df$x, df$y, use = "complete.obs") / (sd(df$x)*sd(df$y, na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 0.09313766
cor(df$x, df$y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
[1] 0.09313766
```

Comment: I'm sorry (still learning R) could you elaborate on what you mean about the vector being pairwise complete?

Comment: Thanks!, I think I get it now.